# How to change the colour of a row in the TableView of QML on a mouse event?

Tags: javascript, qt, qml, qt5

So, when a user clicks on a row, the colour of that row should change.
This is what I have tried. It doesn't work.

Here `table` is the id of my QML `TableView`.

Let default color be blue and on click it should change to red.

```
   rowDelegate:
            Rectangle
            {
                id: rowDel
                color:
                {
                    var activeRow = table.currentRow === styleData.row;
                                (activeRow ? mouse_area.pressed ? "red" : "blue" : "white")
                }

                border.width: 1
                height: 52
                width: 2000

                MouseArea
                {
                    id: mouse_area
                    anchors.fill: parent
                }
            }
```

Comment: If you add an `onClicked` handler to your MouseArea, does it get called? (Put a print statement inside.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### Solution

Instead of [`styleData.row`](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qml-qtquick-controls-tableview.html#rowDelegate-prop) use `styleData.selected`.

### Example

Here is an example I wrote for you to demonstrate the proposed solution:

```
import QtQuick 2.15
import QtQuick.Window 2.15
import QtQuick.Controls 1.4

Window {
    width: 320
    height: 200
    visible: true
    title: qsTr("TableView")

    ListModel {
        id: libraryModel
        ListElement {
            title: "A Masterpiece"
            author: "Gabriel"
        }
        ListElement {
            title: "Brilliance"
            author: "Jens"
        }
        ListElement {
            title: "Outstanding"
            author: "Frederik"
        }
    }

    TableView {
        id: table

        anchors.fill: parent
        model: libraryModel

        rowDelegate: Rectangle {
            color: styleData.selected ? "red" : "blue"
            width: 2000
            height: 40
            border.width: 1
        }

        TableViewColumn {
            role: "title"
            title: "Title"
            width: 100
        }

        TableViewColumn {
            role: "author"
            title: "Author"
            width: 200
        }
    }
}
```

### Result

The provided example produces the following result:

[image: TableView selected row 2]

With the second row selected.

[image: TableView selected row 3]

With the last row selected.

Comment: Brilliant! Got a solution for Qt Quick Controls 2? Looks like version 1 was deprecated in Qt 5.11 and was removed in Qt 6.0. The new `TableView` seems a lot harder to do these basic things.